# use offset to refer an array in excel

Tags: excel

I was trying to calculate the R-squared value of two arrays using RSQ function. One array is fixed, another is located in different columns. I want to generate a code so that i will be able to generate R-squared value for all variables by drag down the cell.

i tried
=RSQ($H$4:$H$102,OFFSET($A$4:$A$102,0,ROW(Z3)-2))

where ROW(Z3)-2 = 1 and the offset part should refer to B4:B102.

The result of RSQ was #N/A. But when I tried SUM(OFFSET($A$4:$A$102,0,ROW(Z3)-2)) it do gives me a correct sum for B4:B102. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=RSQ($H$4:$H$102,OFFSET($A$4:$A$102,0,MAX(ROW(Z3)-2)))
```

The problem seems to be that `ROW(n)` returns a 1x1 array. I'm guessing Excel is complaining that the 1x1 array is not sized the same as other arrays you are using. Wrapping it in `MAX` seems to work around this by returning the value in that array, and calculation goes on.

I must say I have not noticed this behavior before. Good question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution perfectly solve my problem, and thank you for the explanation as well.